# Sorting date Slicer in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I already use custom lists in excel and the sorting for date slicer actually works fine except for (Nov'). Anyone can help me? Below is the picture for problem I am facing.

[image]

Comment: Create [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), describe your expected output

Comment: my expected out is that Nov'19 should be before Dec'19. I don't know why all months is sorting nicely except for Nov got problem.

Comment: without a sample, the case is hard to reproduce & troubleshoot. Mind sharing one..? ( :